# add an asp .net core application to a ruby on rails site hosted on a linux server

Tags: linux-networking, asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I am new to web hosting, and please forgive my ignorance.

my company has a website, and the site is an Ruby on Rails application with Passenger hosted on a linux server.

I would like to know if it is possible to install an additional asp .net core application to the same site to provide some functionalities.

for example, if the original site is "https://rubyapp.xyz.com", what I would like to do is to route "https://rubyapp.xyz.com/aspnetcore" to an asp .net core application installed on the same server.

I am not sure if this is going to work, I would highly appreciate any advice from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft seems to think so, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux, and who am I to contradict µicro$oft.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks a lot! that's what I want to hear. :)

Comment: Wouldn't mind hearing how it goes.

Comment: uh..., so the first reply was more like "good luck"?  @GerardH.Pille

Comment: My answer wasn't sarcasm, if that is what you imply.  I do wish you good luck, seriously.  I wouldn't use µ$ myself, always thought one couldn't find anything more evil, but that was before the advent of internet sewer Faecesbook and consorts.  µ$ seems to take Linux quite seriously nowadays, so, if you have an existing ASP application, you may stand a fair chance with their dotnet implementation on Linux.  I really would like to hear from your experience with it.

Comment: Thanks again for your patience with me. It may take some time to do the actual implementation, but I will try to give updates if this is going anywhere.